# lua reading file dont work

Tags: arrays, lua, referrals

I don't know why but my function doesn't work.

I want to create an array `playerMonster`, each node of `playerMonster` is a different monster. but when I try every node is the same
please help.

```
local monster = {no, power, def, speed, evade, hit, maxhp, spow, potype, lvevo, move1,mov2,smove,pmove, lv, numgame}
local playerMonster = {}

local function readfile()
local path = system.pathForFile("playerpo.txt")
local file = io.open(path, "r")
if file then
    io.input(file)
    for i = 1, player.nummonster do
    monster.no = io.read("*number")
    monster.power = io.read("*number")
    monster.def = io.read("*number")
    monster.speed = io.read("*number")
    monster.evade = io.read("*number")
    monster.hit = io.read("*number")
    monster.maxhp = io.read("*number")
    monster.spow = io.read("*number")
    monster.potype = io.read("*number")
    monster.lvevo = io.read("*number")
    monster.move1 = io.read("*number")
    monster.move2 = io.read("*number")
    monster.smove = io.read("*number")
    monster.pmove = io.read("*number")
    monster.lv = io.read("*number")
    monster.numgame = io.read("*number")
    playerMonster[i] = monster
    end
    for i = 1,5 do
    print(i, playerMonster[i].no)-- all is same
    end
end
file:close()
end
```

Comment: Try `... for i = 1, player.nummonster do local monster = {}; monster.no = io.read("*number") ...`

Comment: thank you verymuch, it really help